# jQuery control not displaying on browser on Windows Phone (IE II, WinPhone 8.1)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, windows-phone

To get my feet wet with MVC4 I created a simple default Internet Application in Visual Studio 2012.

I added a simple jQuery based countdown control and a text box that has a datepicker control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
         style: "flip",
         year: 2013,
         month: 11,
         day: 13,
         hour: 18,
         width: 300,
         height: 40
      });
</script>

<input type="text" id="dp" class="datefield"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".datefield").datepicker();
   });
</script>
```

I signed up for a free host and published the website and all is working well on all the current desktop browsers and phone browsers except for my Windows Phone browser. The datepicker works fine, but the countdown is not working. I checked the webpage where I got the countdown control from and my phone isn't displaying the countdown on that page either.

I found a webpage that tells me my phone is running IE 11 so I upgraded my desktop browser to IE 11 and on the desktop my test page is working fine even when I emulate Windows Phone in the F12 console.

I looked into getting the Windows Phone SDK, but I need to run Win7 for my job and apparently you need to be running Win8 to use the Windows Phone SDK.

Can someone explain why the countdown isn't working on my Windows Phone or how I could debug it?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

TIA!

UPDATE:
I was able to create a workaround for the JavaScript code. The problem was on a line that used the "||" operator in quite a long succession of tests. I broke the tests out into individual tests and the problem went away. I haven't figured out the exact problem in the series of tests but the real point of my question was "how" could I debug it.

In the end I used the 'printf' approach (well 'alert') to simply find the line of code that was causing the problem. For this error the approach worked, but for a more insidious issue I would really prefer to have a better debugging environment. If the problem had been on a desktop browser I could have used the built in JavaScript debugging tools in the browsers (I only tried FF and IE but would hope Chrome and Safari would have similar tools).

I would still be interested in finding a better way to debug issues on the windows phone browser so if some someone has a better solution I'd love to hear it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See update in original question.

So you don't have to search:

I was able to create a workaround for the JavaScript code. The problem was on a line that used the "||" operator in quite a long succession of tests. I broke the tests out into individual tests and the problem went away. I haven't figured out the exact problem in the series of tests but the real point of my question was "how" could I debug it.

In the end I used the 'printf' approach (well 'alert') to simply find the line of code that was causing the problem. For this error the approach worked, but for a more insidious issue I would really prefer to have a better debugging environment. If the problem had been on a desktop browser I could have used the built in JavaScript debugging tools in the browsers (I only tried FF and IE but would hope Chrome and Safari would have similar tools).

I would still be interested in finding a better way to debug issues on the windows phone browser so if some someone has a better solution I'd love to hear it.

Thanks.